# How can I use streams to group elements by a remainder of division by the give divisor?

Tags: java, java-stream

I hava an inputStream of Integers and some number as a devisor. I want to have a result like this:
sumByRemainder(3, (1,2,3,4,5)) ->
(0, 3),
(1, 5),
(2, 7)

What's wrong with the code below?

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> sumByRemainder(Integer devisor, IntStream is) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = is.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s % devisor, 
Collectors.summingInt()));
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
return is
       .boxed()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s % devisor, Collectors.summingInt(x -> x)));
```

Note that you should to use `.boxed()` to get primitive value from the `IntStream`, instead the value in `groupingBy` is considered as `Object` and you can't devide `Object` by `Integer`

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should *box* the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`, as `Collector`s only work with the wrapper types and not primitives.

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> sumByRemainder(int divisor, IntStream is) {
    return is.boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s % divisor,
        Collectors.summingInt(x -> x)));
}
```